# Symfony2: Locale Switcher implementation without session/controller

Tags: php, localization, symfony

So, seems everything ok after 3.5 hours......

Two pages:

localhost.lo/xx/about

localhost.lo/xx/hello/{name}

where xx - several locales described in routing.yml

-- routing.yml

```
home:
    resource: "@JetInformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: ^en|de|ru|uk|pl$
```

-- JetInformBundle routing.yml

```
hello:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: JetInformBundle:Default:index, name: 'alexander' }

about:
    pattern:  /about
    defaults: { _controller: JetInformBundle:Default:about }
```

-- DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace Jet\InformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('JetInformBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
                             array('name' => $name, 'matches' => $this->matchAction($request)));
    }

    public function aboutAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('JetInformBundle:Default:about.html.twig',
                              array('matches' => $this->matchAction($request)));
    }

    protected function matchAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->get('router')->match($request->getRequestUri());
    }
}
```

-- index.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>{{ 'hello.name'|trans }} {{ name }}!</h1>
<h3>{{ 'your.locale'|trans }} [{{ app.request.get('_locale') }}]</h3>

{% include 'JetInformBundle:Default:locales.html.twig'
            with {
                'uripath': 'hello',
                'params': {
                    'name': app.request.get('name')
                }
            }
%}

{% include 'JetInformBundle:Default:matches.html.twig'
            with { 'matches': matches } %}

<div>
    <p>{{ 'return.to'|trans }} <a href="{{ path('about', { '_locale': app.request.get('_locale') }) }}">About</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

-- about.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>{% trans %}about.page{% endtrans %}</h1>
<h3>{% trans %}your.locale{% endtrans %} [{{ app.request.get('_locale') }}]</h3>

{% include 'JetInformBundle:Default:locales.html.twig'
            with { 'uripath': 'about', 'params': {}} %}

{% include 'JetInformBundle:Default:matches.html.twig'
            with { 'matches': matches } %}

<div>
    <p>{% trans%}return.to{% endtrans%} <a href="{{ path('hello', { 'name': app.request.get('name'), '_locale': app.request.get('_locale') }) }}">Hello</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

-- locales.html.twig

```
{% if not params %}
    {% set params = {} %}
{% endif %}

<div class="langs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            {% if app.request.get('_locale') == 'ru' %}
                Русский
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path(uripath, params|merge({ '_locale': 'ru' })) }}">Русский</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        <li>
            {% if app.request.get('_locale') == 'en' %}
                English
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path(uripath, params|merge({ '_locale': 'en' })) }}">English</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        <li>
            {% if app.request.get('_locale') == 'uk' %}
                Украiнська
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path(uripath, params|merge({ '_locale': 'uk' })) }}">Украiнська</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        <li>
            {% if app.request.get('_locale') == 'de' %}
                Deutsch
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path(uripath, params|merge({ '_locale': 'de' })) }}">Deutsch</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
        <li>
            {% if app.request.get('_locale') == 'pl' %}
                Polish
            {% else %}
                <a href="{{ path(uripath, params|merge({ '_locale': 'pl' })) }}">Polish</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

-- matches.html.twig

```
<h5>Matches</h5>
<ol>
{% for key, value in matches %}
    <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Solution without session based R/W and without LocalesController with additional request.
Hey, All, what do you think about ?
May be other solutions, another opinions ??
Just interesting...
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual question here? What problem are you trying to get help with?

Comment: http://knpbundles.com/search?q=localebundle

Comment: Not exactly sure what the question is here, but I would recommend you take a look at the JMSi18nRouting Bundle: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle